# How do i center a quote, vertically and horizontally in latex?

Tags: latex, vertical-alignment, centering

I have a quote on a blank page in latex. I have managed to center it horizontally, however, when i try to center it vertically it gives me some problems. I have tried

```
\vspace{}
\begin{quote}
\centering
quote
\end{quote}
```

However it doesnt work.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```
\vspace*{\fill} 
\begin{quote} 
\centering 
quote 
\end{quote}
\vspace*{\fill}
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to upvote/accept answers if you found them to be useful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use increments of `\paperheight`. For instance if you wish to have the quote 1/3 down the page you can do

```
\vspace*{0.15\pageheight}  

\begin{quote} 
    \centering 
    quote 
\end{quote}

\newpage
```

**Note**:
The multiplication factor is based on having twice the pageheight, therefore 1/3 = 0.3 . 0.3/2 = 0.15 -> 0.15\pageheight

Rather than adding a fraction of vertical space underneath it is easier to tell continuing content to start at the top of the next page with `\newpage`.